# Active to Passive Voice

Tags: grammar

The girl arranged the flowers in the vase beautifully.

(1) The flowers in the vase were beautifully arranged by the girl.

(2) The flowers were beautifully arranged in the vase by the girl.

Which one is suitable?

Comment: Suitable to what context? Both are grammatical enough, but meaning and emphasis vary somewhat between them.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *in the vase* might be a qualifier for the NP (noun phrase) *the flowers*, or it might be an adjunct to the verb *arranged*, specifying how/where the arrangement was made.

The active sentence is ambiguous: *in the vase* might take either role.

The two passive sentences distinguish these structures: in 1) the phrase qualifies *the flowers*, while in 2) it modifies the verb.

Both are grammatical, both make sense. To decide which is more appropriate you would need to decide which of the two meanings was intended by the ambiguous active sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Even though both seem grammatically correct the first sentence would be more accurate than the second in meaning to the original sentence because in the second sentence it would seem the sequence of events are different from the first.

> The original and the first imply that the flowers were already in the vase before being arranged but not so with the second.